# Python / BeautifulSoup webscraper returning "None"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

trying to build a webscraper to return lists of freelance gig postings on different websites into one place. My code is below and it keeps returning "None". I'm a bit stuck at this point, if you can help identify why it keeps doing this that would be great.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

res1 = requests.get('https://www.airtasker.com/tasks/?task_states=posted&lat=-33.7918&lon=151.0806&location_name=Eastwood%2C%20NSW&radius=20000000&carl_ids=&task_types=both&max_price=9999&min_price=5&search_term=python&badges=&sort_by=posted_desc')  # this is where we will scrape the info from
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(res1.text, 'html.parser')  # this tells BS to give us HTML code for the page
links1 = soup1.select('.new-task-list-item new-task-list-item--open')  # link of each gig
subtext1 = soup1.select('.new-task-list-item__date at-icon-calendar')  # date of each gig

res2 = requests.get('https://www.airtasker.com/tasks/?task_states=posted&lat=-33.7918&lon=151.0806&location_name=Eastwood%2C%20NSW&radius=20000000&carl_ids=&task_types=both&max_price=9999&min_price=5&search_term=web%20developer&badges=&sort_by=posted_desc')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res2.text, 'html.parser')
links2 = soup2.select('.new-task-list-item new-task-list-item--open')
subtext2 = soup2.select('.new-task-list-item__date at-icon-calendar')

res3 = requests.get('https://www.upwork.com/freelance-jobs/website/')
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(res3.text, 'html.parser')
links3 = soup3.select('.job-title')
subtext3 = soup3.select('.text-muted')

res4 = requests.get('https://www.upwork.com/freelance-jobs/data-science/')
soup4 = BeautifulSoup(res4.text, 'html.parser')
links4 = soup4.select('.job-title')
subtext4 = soup4.select('.text-muted')

res5 = requests.get('https://www.upwork.com/freelance-jobs/bot-development/')
soup5 = BeautifulSoup(res5.text, 'html.parser')
links5 = soup5.select('.job-title')
subtext5 = soup5.select('.text-muted')

res6 = requests.get('https://www.upwork.com/freelance-jobs/python-script/')
soup6 = BeautifulSoup(res6.text, 'html.parser')
links6 = soup6.select('.job-title')
subtext6 = soup6.select('.text-muted')

mega_links = links1 + links2 + links3 + links4 + links5 + links6
mega_subtext = subtext1 + subtext2 + subtext3 + subtext4 + subtext5 + subtext6

def extract(links, subtexts):
    joblist = []
    for indx, item in enumerate(links):
        title = item.getText()
        href = item.get('href')
        joblist.append({'title': title, 'link': href})
        return joblist

pprint.pprint(extract(mega_links , mega_subtext))
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `links` is empty? If it is empty, then the `for` loop doesn't run and your `extract` function implicitly returns None.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what exactly you are trying to extract from the scraped web page requests. Here's what I tried from my end:
Your `links` variable are null or empty lists since there is no such querySelector present for the web page you're trying to scrape. For example, the console of the first web page that you are scraping *(the element you're trying to scrape doesn't exist)*:
[image]

I would recommend you to confirm the element you're trying to scrape and confirm it's class.

Another Point of Consideration:

When you will print your `soup` variables you will notice that you get `CloudFare` as the output.

Comment: That image is not required to be converted into text since it is just the output of what the console shows when the querySelector is passed.

Comment: Im trying to scrape the titles and links of each job posting on the links. I got those class names from the HTML on each webpage, which I thought were the classes of the links/titles.